# LEFT OUTER JOIN of two collections

Tags: java, collections

The question is pretty much in the title. I'm looking for an algorithm more efficient than full search through the collections.

I have two collections:

```
List<Map<TypeId, Object> > col1;
List<Entity> col2;
```

Where

```
public enum TypeId{
    PLAYER,
    PARTNER,
    PLATFORM,
    AMOUNT
}
```

and

```
public class Entity{
    private int player_id;
    private int platform_id
    private BigDecimal amount;

    //GET, SET
}
```

The `col1` collection which is of the type `List<Map<TypeId, Object> >` contains only `PLAYER, PARTNER,  PLATFORM` `TypeId`s.

I need to write a method:

```
public List<Map<TypeId, Object> > merge(List<Map<TypeId, Object> > col1, List<Entity> col2){
    //Impl
}
```

Which is going to produce `List<Map<TypeId, Object> >` each the entry `entry` of the map contains additional key-value `(AMOUNT, AMOUNT's value)`  where `AMOUNT's value` is the value of the `amount` field of the instance `e` of `Entity` if `e.player_id = entry.get(PLAYER) && e.platform_id = entry.get(PLATFORM)` and `null` otherwise.

In fact, the operation would be the same as

```
col1 LEFT OUTER JOIN 
col2 ON e.player_id = entry.get(PLAYER) && e.platform_id = entry.get(PLATFORM)
```

SAMPLE:

```
col1:
[{PLATFORM: 1, PARTNER: 1, PLAYER: 1},
 {PLATFORM: 1, PARTNER: 3, PLAYER: 1},
 {PLATFORM: 2, PARTNER: 1, PLAYER: 2}
 {PLATFORM: 3, PARTNER: 4, PLAYER: 5}]

col2:
[Entity(platform_id = 1, player_id = 1, amount = 100),
Entity(platform_id = 2, player_id = 2, amount = 200),
Entity(platform_id = 3, player_id = 4, amount = 300)]

result:
[{PLATFORM: 1, PARTNER: 1, PLAYER: 1, AMOUNT: 100},
 {PLATFORM: 1, PARTNER: 3, PLAYER: 1, AMOUNT: 100},
 {PLATFORM: 2, PARTNER: 1, PLAYER: 2, AMOUNT: 200},
 {PLATFORM: 3, PARTNER: 4, PLAYER: 5, AMOUNT: null}]
```

Comment: It would help us to visualize the requirement in a better way if you provide sample data showing the input and expected output as well. It's often easier to model objects and query them for data if you have sample input and output data in front of you.

Comment: @ChetanKinger Could you look at the sample?

Comment: So `PARTNER` does not impact the `join` condition?

Comment: @ChetanKinger Exactly. That looks like LEFT OUTER JOIN on the condition I provided, doesn't?

Comment: I don't think that's a left outer join. I think that `PARTNER` is just not the part of the `UNIQUE` key of `Entity`. Are you restricted by using a `List<Entity>` and a `List<Map<TypeId,Object>>` or are you open to changing your data-structures?

Comment: @ChetanKinger Don;t see how it makes the operation not being a left outer join.

Comment: @ChetanKinger Well, changing of the data structure would be undesirable, yes. I'd like to create a new collection containing the desirable result.

Comment: An outer join is used to return matching rows + non matching rows using keys that define the uniqueness. How does your output confirm to this definition.

Comment: Your data structures are not very well suitable for the requested task. By the way, is Java 8 allowed?

Comment: @TagirValeev I myself are not using Java 8, but also would like to look at the solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's easier to make changes in-place, modifying the `col1` list instead of creating the new `List`. Here's Java-8 solution:

```
public List<Map<TypeId, Object> > merge(List<Map<TypeId, Object> > col1, List<Entity> col2){
    col1.forEach(map -> map.put(TypeId.AMOUNT, 
        col2.stream()
            .filter(e -> e.player_id == (int)map.get(TypeId.PLAYER) && 
                         e.platform_id == (int)map.get(TypeId.PLATFORM))
            .findFirst().map(e -> e.amount).orElse(null)
        ));
    return col1;
}
```

I suppose that changing the `col1` in place is satisfactory in this case. Note that even if you store the result into a new list, it will be useless if you modify the existing maps. Thus to make the result totally independent from the `col1`, you will have to copy all the maps.

Also note that it's not very effective as for each `col1` entry it traverses the `col2`, so the complexity is roughly `col1.size()*col2.size()`. It's probably better in your case to throw away an `Entity` class and create a new one which stores platformId and playerId only (with properly implemented `equals` and `hashCode`) and use it as map key:

```
public static class PlatformAndPlayer {
    private final int playerId, platformId;

    public PlatformAndPlayer(int playerId, int platformId) {
        this.playerId = playerId;
        this.platformId = platformId;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        final int prime = 31;
        int result = 1;
        result = prime * result + platformId;
        result = prime * result + playerId;
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj)
            return true;
        if (obj == null)
            return false;
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
            return false;
        PlatformAndPlayer other = (PlatformAndPlayer) obj;
        if (platformId != other.platformId)
            return false;
        if (playerId != other.playerId)
            return false;
        return true;
    }
}
```

This way instead of `col2` list you will have a `Map`:

```
Map<PlatformAndPlayer, BigDecimal> col2 = new HashMap<>();
col2.put(new PlatformAndPlayer(1, 1), BigDecimal.valueOf(100));
col2.put(new PlatformAndPlayer(2, 2), BigDecimal.valueOf(200));
col2.put(new PlatformAndPlayer(3, 4), BigDecimal.valueOf(300));
```

Now your task can be solved easily and effectively (even with Java 5):

```
public static List<Map<TypeId, Object>> merge(
        List<Map<TypeId, Object>> col1,
        Map<PlatformAndPlayer, BigDecimal> col2) {
    for (Map<TypeId, Object> map : col1) {
        map.put(TypeId.AMOUNT, col2.get(new PlatformAndPlayer(
            (int) map.get(TypeId.PLAYER), (int) map.get(TypeId.PLATFORM))));
    }
    return col1;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The [Guava](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/GuavaExplained) library provides functional idioms that are perfect for these sort of transformations. Here's an example implementation of your method using Guava that does not require changing the method signature:

```
public List<Map<TypeId, Object>> merge(List<Map<TypeId, Object>> col1,
        List<Entity> col2) {                

    // create a lookup table for getting the amounts
    // based on entities (entity keys)
    final Map<Entity, BigDecimal> entityLookupTable = Maps.toMap(col2,
             new Function<Entity, BigDecimal>() {
                 @Override
                 public BigDecimal apply(Entity entity) {
                     return entity.getAmount();
                 }
    });

    // transform the col1 list using a transform function 
    // that adds the AMOUNT fetched from the lookup table to each entry map
    return Lists.transform(col1, new Function<Map<TypeId, Object>,
                                             Map<TypeId, Object>>() {

        @Override
        public Map<TypeId, Object> apply(Map<TypeId, Object> typeToValueMap) {

                    Entity keyWrapper = new Entity(
                            new EntityKey(
                                (Integer) typeToValueMap.get(TypeId.PLAYER),
                                (Integer) typeToValueMap.get(TypeId.PLATFORM)),
                            null);

                    typeToValueMap.put(TypeId.AMOUNT,
                            entityLookupTable.get(keyWrapper));

                    return typeToValueMap;
                }
            });
}
```

What is required, however, is to create an `EntityKey` class that identifies an entity (analogous to primary key in the DB). This class can then be used for implementing `equals` (and `hashCode`) in `Entity`, enabling storing entities in a lookup map.

```
public class EntityKey {

    private int player_id;
    private int platform_id;

    public EntityKey(int player_id, int platform_id) {
        this.player_id = player_id;
        this.platform_id = platform_id;
    }

    /* Generated by Eclipse */
    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        final int prime = 31;
        int result = 1;
        result = prime * result + platform_id;
        result = prime * result + player_id;
        return result;
    }

    /* Generated by Eclipse */
    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj)
            return true;
        if (obj == null)
            return false;
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
            return false;
        EntityKey other = (EntityKey) obj;
        if (platform_id != other.platform_id)
            return false;
        if (player_id != other.player_id)
            return false;
        return true;
    }        
}

public class Entity {

    private EntityKey key;
    private BigDecimal amount;

    public Entity(EntityKey key, BigDecimal amount) {
        this.key = key;
        this.amount = amount;
    }      

    /* Generated by Eclipse */
    /* Simply delegates to EntityKey */
    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        final int prime = 31;
        int result = 1;
        result = prime * result + ((key == null) ? 0 : key.hashCode());
        return result;
    }

    /* Generated by Eclipse */
    /* Simply delegates to EntityKey */
    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj)
            return true;
        if (obj == null)
            return false;
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
            return false;
        Entity other = (Entity) obj;
        if (key == null) {
            if (other.key != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!key.equals(other.key))
            return false;
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * @return the amount
     */
    public BigDecimal getAmount() {
        return amount;
    }
}
```